# Why hydrodynamic turbulence without heat terms matters?

Tags: turbulence, weather, navier-stokes

A lot of research is made on turbulence in "pure" Navier-Stokes equations ([NSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations)). There is a notion of energy cascade when energy comes from larger scales to lower scales and than dissipate.
However *physically* energy does not just vanish, it turns into heat.

And (if I understand right) presence of heat itself produces a lot of movement. So taking heat into account should change drastically the behavior of the system.

So my question is -- why so much effort is spent on studying pure NSE if they are unphysical and this effort might be useless for a study of actual behavior (when one includes heat terms in NSE)? I know that people study NSE with heat as well but my impression that this field is much less active (at least from fundamental viewpoint) in the case of pure NSE.

I am thinking about a system with a constant force producing turbulence and a heat bath.